# Is there a way to tell at run-time what API level an Android device is running?

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the API level used by a given Android device?

I want to make one version of an application that does not use AnticipateOvershootInterpolator() and another that uses it for devices using API levels greater than 3.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Look at `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK` (and `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` for newer devices).

Answer (score 12):

You can use this constant: [`android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT). It returns one of [these values](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html).

Comment: `SDK_INT` was added in Android 1.6 (API level 4). For apps only supporting that API level or higher, `SDK_INT` is a great answer. However, in this case, the OP is asking to detect ">3 Api level devices", suggesting support for API level 3. In that case, using the older `SDK` string and converting it to an integer is the better solution.